# Can't run app on local Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I got an existing project on Java and using Tomcat server... I installed it all and fixed all errors at build time (fixed dependencies) and seems app became to run but it is still unavailable in my browser and prints strange log:

```
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.81
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 11 2017 10:21:27 UTC
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.81.0
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_80-b15
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         W:\Media\Projects\Eclipse projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=W:\Media\Projects\Eclipse projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=W:\Media\Projects\Eclipse projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\conte\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;.
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1076 ms
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
сен 18, 2017 11:44:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.81
сен 18, 2017 11:44:38 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [107] milliseconds.
сен 18, 2017 11:44:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
сен 18, 2017 11:44:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
сен 18, 2017 11:44:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1062 ms
```

And in the browser:
[image: Screenshot]
Can anyone explain what does it mean? And what side do I need to search? I am from C# ASP.Net, so really get it bad yet.

Comment: The messages are just startup log messages.  I see no errors, so Tomcat looks fine.  I think the problem is the URL you typed into the browser.  Your URL should include a context name (e.g. the name of your WAR file): http://localhost:8080/your-war-file.  If you have an index page specified in your web.xml that will come up.  If not, you should give the URL of some page in the app.

Comment: Seems to me the application wasn't deployed

Comment: Thank you I will check it now

Comment: @VitaliiKravchenko, но публикация на сервер, вроде, нормально прошла

Comment: @Шах Please only talk English on SO.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry... Just I said I didn't notice any records about fail deployment.

Comment: @Шах Open Tomcat Web application manager and you will see whether your application deployed.

Comment: @VitaliiKravchenko thank you very much I will check